# Mongoose validation not working properly in mocha test

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

I am building a REST api with nodejs, using mongoose and mochajs to run some tests. I have the following scheme:

```
var subscriptionTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    typeId          : { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    name            : { type: String, required: true},
    active          : { type: Boolean, required: true }
});
```

Express route:

```
app.post('/1.0/subscriptiontype', subscriptiontype.create);
```

Controller:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    validation.subscriptionTypeValidator(req);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        res.status(400).json({
            errors: errors
        });
    } else {
        var subscriptionType = new SubscriptionType();
        subscriptionType.typeId = parseInt(req.body.typeId);
        subscriptionType.name = req.body.name;
        subscriptionType.active = req.body.active;
        subscriptionType.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                var parsedError = mongooseutility.parseMongooseError(err);
                res.status(400).json({
                    errors: [parsedError]
                });
            } else {
                res.json({identifier: subscriptionType._id});
            }
        });
    }
};
```

The mongoose utility maps the error codes to a more API friendly output (error codes 11001 and 11000 are mapped to a 'duplicate' error, as can be seen in the test).

Mocha before method:

```
before(function(done) {
    db.connection.on('open', function() {
        db.connection.db.dropDatabase(function(err) {
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

I've verified that the database is dropped successfully.

The test itself makes a request using supertest. Before this test, I have a test that creates a subscription type with typeId 4 successfully, so this one should fail:

```
it('Should not create subscription with taken type id', function (done) {
    request(app.privateapi)
        .post('/1.0/subscriptiontype')
        .set('Authorization', authorizationHeader)
        .send({
            typeId: 4,
            name: 'New package',
            active: 1
        })
        .expect(function (res) {
            if (res.status !== 400) {
                throw new Error('Status code was not 400');
            }

            var expectedResponse = { errors: [ { param: 'typeId', msg: 'duplicate' } ] };

            if (JSON.stringify(res.body) !==  JSON.stringify(expectedResponse)) {
                throw new Error('Output was not was as expected');
            }
        })
       .end(done);
});
```

Tests are invoked using grunt-simple-mocha.

This test works the first time, however when I run it a 2nd time it fails on the unique validation. A third time it works again. I've done some searching and found that it probably has something to do with a race condition while recreating indexes, so I've tried restarting mongodb before running the tests again, but that doesn't work. I've found a solution here: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongoose-orm/138qe75dvr/mongoose-unique-index-test-fail but I am not sure how to implement this. Any ideas?

Edit: for now I fixed it by dropping the database in an 'after' method (instead of 'before'). All the tests run fine, but it would be nice to keep the test data after the tests are done, for inspection etc...

Comment: Would you possibly care to share the actual code doing the updates and the actual method of submission? Perhaps consider that software that has been around for some time is less likely to be at fault than your brand new code which has not shared the same test of time. The more you share, the clearer it is to other sets of eyes to observe the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've added some more information.

Comment: Can I just point to the crux of your problem here? So you say 1. Insert: Ok, 2. Insert: Fail, 3. Insert: Ok. And all while submitting the same value into a unique field constraint ( AKA Index ). So in a sane way this is all about the invocation and where and when actual collection artifacts get "dropped". So while the additional information is useful, the real case is "how are you invoking this" and how we ensure that indexes are created in place. Kind of what was hinted at in the referenced post. It's about timing and succession. If you still need help then that's what you ask.

Comment: Right, I am not entirely sure what you mean, but the tests are invoked with the grunt-simple-mocha task. the before() method is the first method in the test suite that is called.

Answer (score 0):

You are not testing the creation of your tables so you can just empty your collections instead of creating the db.

Something along those lines (not tested):

```
beforeEach(function(done){
    var models = Object.keys(mongoose.models);
    var expects = models.length;
    if(expects == 0) return done();
    var removeCount = 1;
    //maybe use async or something else but whatever
    models.forEach(function(model){
        model.remove({}, function(){
            if(removeCount == expects){
                done();
            }
            removeCount++;
        })
    });
});
```